# Job Scheduling in clean architecture

Tags: clean-architecture

Imagine having the entity Counter and a use case that creates it. Moreover the business logic requires that every time a counter gets created a background task that increases the counter every 1s must be started too, should terms like "scheduling" appear in a use case?

```
class Counter{constructor(public id: String, public count: number) {}}

interface CounterIncreaseScheduler {
  schedule(counterID: string): void
}

class CreateCounterUseCase {
  constructor(private counterIncreaseScheduler: CounterIncreaseScheduler) {}
  execute(counterID: string) {
    // create counter
    // persist counter
    this.counterIncreaseScheduler.schedule(counterID)
  }
}

class NaiveCounterIncreaseSchedulerIMpl implements CounterIncreaseScheduler  {
  schedule(counterID: string): void {
    setInterval(() => {
      // call increase counter use case 
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

Also, is it idiomatic to spawn an input adapter from an output adapter?
As in the example above, the output adapter CounterIncreaseScheduler would need to spawn a background task that would become an input  adapter that increments the counter through another use case.
What about implementing some sort of polling/pubsub? Is it up to developer decision?

Comment: A "User" can be a *person* or a *system.*  Does that answer your first question?

Comment: `is it idiomatic to spawn an input adapter from an output adapter?` -- Generally no; I think that would be an SRP violation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry my first question is if terms like "schedule"(or maybe even "broadcastEvent") may appear in a use case. Maybe I'm missing your point. 
So anyway if I can't spawn an input adapter from an output one, what else can I do? Implement a polling system that listen for new counters?

Comment: My point is that a *system* can be a participant in Use Cases.  Any other word that you deem suitable from that perspective should be allowed.

Comment: Oh I see, got it

Comment: As to the output adapter spawning an input adapter, nothing prevents you from doing that, but I don't think you can call it an output adapter anymore.

Comment: Yeah I see your point but if not that then i would need to broadcast an event in a use case and then listen for that event to actually spawn the background task. That shouldn't violate SRP right

Comment: You would have to make the determination as to which approach is better for your specific situation.